# SKLearn Naive Bayes: add feature after tfidf vectorization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf, naivebayes

So I have been tasked with training a model on phone call transcripts. The following code does this. A little background info:
- x is a list of strings, each ith element is an entire transcript
- y is a list of booleans, stating the outcome of a call being positive or negative.

The following code works, but here is my issue. **I want to include call duration as a feature to train on.** I'd assume after the TFIDF transformer that vectorizes the transcripts, I would just concatenate the call duration feature to the TFIDF output right? Maybe this is easier than I think, but I have the transcripts and the durations all in the pandas data frame you see at the beginning of the code. **So if I have that data frame column (numpy array) of durations, what do I need to do to add that feature into my model?**

Additional Questions:

- Am I missing a fundamental assumption about Naive Bayes model that limits me to vectorized strings?
- At which step in my pipeline do I add the new feature?
- Can this even be done in a pipeline or do I have to break it apart to do something like this?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2


def main():
filename = 'QA_training.pkl'
splitRatio = 0.67
dataframe = loadData(filename)
x, y = getTrainingData(dataframe)
print len(x), len(y)

x_train, x_test = splitDataset(x, splitRatio)
y_train, y_test = splitDataset(y, splitRatio)

#x_train = np.asarray(x_train)

percentiles = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

MNNB_pipe = Pipeline([('vec', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('select', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),('clf', MultinomialNB())])
MNNB_param_grid = {
#'vec__max_features': (10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000),
'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
'tfidf__sublinear_tf': (True, False),
'vec__binary': (True, False),
'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
'clf__alpha': (1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001),
'select__percentile': percentiles
}
MNNB_search = GridSearchCV(MNNB_pipe, param_grid=MNNB_param_grid, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
MNNB_search = MNNB_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
MNNB_search_best_cv = cross_val_score(MNNB_search.best_estimator_, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)

SGDC_pipe = Pipeline([('vec', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('select', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),('clf', SGDClassifier())])
SGDC_param_grid = {
#'vec__max_features': [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 10000],
'tfidf__use_idf': [True, False],
'tfidf__sublinear_tf': [True, False],
'vec__binary': [True, False],
'tfidf__norm': ['l1', 'l2'],
'clf__loss': ['modified_huber','log'],
'clf__penalty': ['l1','l2'],
'clf__alpha': [1e-3],
'clf__n_iter': [5,10],
'clf__random_state': [42],
'select__percentile': percentiles
}
SGDC_search = GridSearchCV(SGDC_pipe, param_grid=SGDC_param_grid, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
SGDC_search = SGDC_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
SGDC_search_best_cv = cross_val_score(SGDC_search.best_estimator_, x_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)

# pre_SGDC = SGDC_clf.predict(x_test)
# print (np.mean(pre_SGDC == y_test))

mydata = [{'model': MNNB_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'],'features': MNNB_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['select'], 'mean_cv_scores': MNNB_search_best_cv.mean()},
          #{'model': GNB_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['classifier'],'features': GNB_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['select'], 'mean_cv_scores': GNB_search_best_cv.mean()},
          {'model': SGDC_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'],'features': SGDC_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['select'], 'mean_cv_scores': SGDC_search_best_cv.mean()}]
model_results_df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
model_results_df.to_csv("best_model_results.csv")
```

Comment: FWIW, you might want to condense your CountVectorizer + TfidfTransformer into a simple TfidfVectorizer -- But that's just a minor code simplification point.  It doesn't change the algorithm at all or anything.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that observation!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, sklearn pipelines are API driven -- There's no real magic that happens in the pipeline itself.  So, from that perspective, you should be able to create your own wrapper around `TfidfVectorizer` that does what you want it to do.  For example, let's assume that you have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['foo text', 'bar text'], 'duration': [1, 2]})
```

you could probably implement your transform as follows:

```
class MyVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, tfidf_kwargs=None):
        self._tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(**(tfidf_kwargs or None))

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self._tfidf.fit(X['text'], y)
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        self.fit(X)
        return self.transform(X, copy=False)

    def transform(self, X, copy=True):
        result = self._tfidf.transform(X['text'], copy=copy)
        # result is a sparse matrix.  I'm not sure of a clean way
        # to add a column to a sparse matrix.  If you have the
        # memory, you can use a dense matrix instead...
        return np.column_stack((result, X['duration']))
```

And then I think you should be all set to use this instead of the original tfidf vectorizer.